# How to forward session in plist file (in IOS)

Tags: ios, session-cookies, plist, ipa

Scenario:

I have a web app and using plist I am trying to install the app on the iPhone, It's working but I want to prevent it from unauthorized access. I have an filter that is checking session value and allow you to download. It's working for apk (Andriod device) but for the IOS we gave plist file and from that file, there is ipa URL.

The problem is I am able to get session value at plist URL but when it comes to ipa URL I am not able to get session value.

Any suggestion on how can I forward this session to ipa URL or any other way to make it secure?

Comment: Let me know here if you need any more details.